# grab previous line in terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Is it possible to grab the previous line in a terminal (`xterm-256color` alone would do) via ANSI sequences, `tput` or the like? Say I have

```
$ pwd
/some/long/path
$ cd $(result)
```

i.e. a programmatic copy-paste (or something akin to `Out[1]` in `ipython`). There's https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec (see https://superuser.com/a/175802/1193313) but I'm curious if there's a less invasive way.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a simple way to do that.

Comment: In general, no.  It greatly depends on your terminal.  You could scrape the pane with `tmux capture-pane`.

Comment: Good find. I'm not looking for anything more general than xterm-256color, but I realize this may not be precise enough

Comment: See also: [Can zsh access the stdout of last run program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117054/can-zsh-access-the-stdout-of-last-run-program)